# Forwarding of return type defined in CRTP derived class incompatibility MSCV/GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, c++20

I am facing an issue with a template function in a CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern) base class that exhibits different behavior on MSVC and GCC compilers. The BaseA base class contains a template member function foo() that is supposed to return a type defined in the inheriting class. However, two different implementations of foo() yield varying results on MSVC and GCC. I have seen several similar stackoverflow threads, but none of them solve my problem.

Check code below or use [this goldbold link](https://godbolt.org/z/Tb5x8WzzE).

```cpp
// Minimal working example

template <typename T>
class BaseA {
    public:
        //// Version 1 (not working on MSVC and GCC)
        //// it is incomplete type usage so it obviously wont work
        //T::value_type foo() const {
        //    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->foo();
        //}

        //// Version 2 (working on MSVC, not working on GCC)
        //// this in my opinion should work everywhere
        //// since type U will be deduced after T from BaseA
        //// but unluckly it does only work on MSVC
        //// GCC error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class DerivedA'
        template <typename U = typename T::value_type>
        U foo() const {
            return static_cast<const T*>(this)->foo();
        }

        //// Version 3 (working on MSVC and GCC)
        //// will work, but "auto" as interface function return value is unaccepted solution.
        //// This is only minimal working example, real program is much bigger and it can lead to
        //// many issues in the future.
        //auto foo() const {
        //    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->foo();
        //}
};

class DerivedA : BaseA<DerivedA> {
    public:
        using value_type = int;

        value_type foo() const {
            return 5;
        }
};

template <typename T>
void some_interface_call(const BaseA<T>& a) {
    auto value = a.foo();
}

int main() {
    BaseA<DerivedA> a;
    some_interface_call(a);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct, general method of conveying such a type?
Is there any way to use `Version 2` under GCC with as few changes as possible?

Comment: `T` is incomplete in CRTP, so you cannot use `T::value_type` in declaration.

Comment: How about external trait, `template <typename T> struct my_value_type; template <> my_value_type<MyObj> { using type = SomeType; /*  but not T::type */ };`.

Comment: @Jarod42 sure I can, just need to wrap it with another template inside a class, check `Version 2` in presented code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work since the template's default has to be valid when the member function template is declared.

The "standard workaround" I've seen for this is to have a `typename U = T` and use `U` like `T` in the declaration:

```cpp
template <typename U = T>
typename U::value_type foo() const {
    return static_cast<const T*>(this)->foo();
}
```

Comment: I checked that and it works under both Linux (GCC) and Windows (MSVC)
I've always used it as in `Version 2` - `template <typename U = T::value_type>`
but I'm mostly programing on windows these days and it had just always worked there. Never though to write it like that. Thanks!